# PayPal button - how to change default payment option from paypal to credit card

Tags: paypal

After user clicks buy button he sees:

(for Paypal payment type)

Email:

Password:

(and small letters with link to credit card payment type)
No PayPal account? Pay using your credit or debit card

(After clicking creditor debit card )

he sees:
I need to create PayPal account (where available)

---

- How to change default payment type to "Pay using your credit or debit card"
- how to make it larger ?
- how to change the string "I need to create a PayPal account (where available). Learn more"  to "CREDIT CARD PAYMENT" ?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to modify this on the checkout if you are usnig Website Payments Standard.  However, if you are using Express Checkout you can set the credit card section to be expanded instead of the log in with PayPal section.  You would just need to pass over the following two variables and values in the SetExpressCheckout API call.

```
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole  
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
```